# Meaning of const T when T is a pointer type?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11, constants

Considering that :

```
char* ptr;             // 1) a non-constant pointer to a non-constant char
const char* ptr;       // 2) a non-constant pointer to a constant char
char* const ptr;       // 3) a constant pointer to a non-constant char
const char* const ptr; // 4) a constant pointer to a constant char
```

When I write :

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void f(const T ptr) 
{;}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char a = 'a';
    f(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the type of `ptr`: 2) or 3) ?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I find pointer declarations to be much less ambiguous if you put the const after the type, as such: `T const * const` and you use the old read-pointer-types-from-right-to-left rule.

Comment: Why the downvote, I don't think it's that bad of a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T` is a pointer to a non-const `char`, so `const T` is a constant pointer to a non-const `char`.